# How I pass parameter in Workflow Template Spark job

Tags: python, apache-spark, workflow, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a problem with my `spark dataproc` workflow.

This works on launch:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark \
--project myproject \
--cluster=mycluster \
--region=europe-west3 \
--jars=gs:path\file.jar,gs://path//depende.jar \
--class=it.flow \
--properties spark.num.executors=2,spark.executor.cores=3,spark.executor.memory=5g,spark.driver.cores=2,spark.driver.memory=10g,spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false,spark.executor.userClassPathFirst=true,spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true,spark.jars.packages=com.google.cloud:google-cloud-logging:2.2.0  
--  20210820 010000 000 0 000 TRY
```

I created a dataproc workflow and the python code to launch it through composer and it works.

Now i have to make the final parameters dynamic (`--    20210820 010000 000 0 000 TRY`)

However, I am unable to pass parameters to the workflow:

```
gcloud dataproc workflow-templates create try1 --region=europe-west3
 
gcloud dataproc workflow-templates add-job spark \
--workflow-template=try1 \
--step-id=create_try1 \
--class=it.flow \
 --region=europe-west3 \
--jars=gs:path\file.jar,gs://path//depende.jar \
 --properties spark.num.executors=2,spark.executor.cores=3,spark.executor.memory=5g,spark.driver.cores=2,spark.driver.memory=10g,spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false,spark.executor.userClassPathFirst=true,spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true,spark.jars.packages=com.google.cloud:google-cloud-logging:2.2.0 \
 -- $arg1 $arg2  
 
gcloud dataproc workflow-templates set-cluster-selector TRY1  --region=europe-west3 --cluster-labels=goog-dataproc-cluster-name=cluster
```

This call:

```
gcloud dataproc workflow-templates instantiate TRY1  --region=europe-west3 --parameters="arg1=20210820"
```

leads to the following error:

> ***ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.workflow-templates.instantiate) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Template does not contain a parameter with name
> arg1.***

How can I resolve the issue?

yaml file

```
id: create_file
jobs:
- sparkJob:
    args:
    - ARG1
    - ARG2
    jarFileUris:
    - gs://mybucket/try_file.jar
    - gs://mybucket/try_dependencies_2.jar
    mainClass: org.apache.hadoop.examples.tryFile
    properties:
      spark.driver.cores: '2'
      spark.driver.memory: 10g
      spark.driver.userClassPathFirst: 'true'
      spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled: 'false'
      spark.executor.cores: '3'
      spark.executor.memory: 5g
      spark.executor.userClassPathFirst: 'true'
      spark.jars.packages: com.google.cloud:google-cloud-logging:2.2.0
      spark.num.executors: '2'
  stepId: create_file_try
  parameters:
- name: ARG1
  fields:
  - jobs['create_file_try'].sparkJob.args[0]
- name: ARG2
  fields:
  - jobs['create_file_try'].sparkJob.args[1]
name: projects/My-project-id/regions/europe-west3/workflowTemplates/create_file
updateTime: '2021-08-25T07:49:59.251096Z'
```

Answer (score 5):

For your workflow template to accept parameters it is much better to use a yaml file. You can get the yaml file when you run your full command `gcloud dataproc workflow-templates add-job spark`. It will return a yaml configuration on the CLI.

In this example I just used [sample code from the Dataproc documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/spark-scala#running_pre-installed_example_code) and used your values at `--properties` for the sake of testing.

NOTE: I used a dummy `project-id` in the yaml files for this example. Make sure you use your actual `project-id` so you won't encounter any problems.

**Sample command:**

```
gcloud dataproc workflow-templates add-job spark \
--workflow-template=try1 \
--step-id=create_try1 \
--class=org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount \
--region=europe-west3 \
--jars=file:///usr/lib/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples.jar \
--properties spark.num.executors=2,spark.executor.cores=3,spark.executor.memory=5g,spark.driver.cores=2,spark.driver.memory=10g,spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false,spark.executor.userClassPathFirst=true,spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true,spark.jars.packages=com.google.cloud:google-cloud-logging:2.2.0 \
-- ARG1 ARG2
```

**CLI output (yaml config):**

```
id: try1
jobs:
- sparkJob:
    args:
    - ARG1
    - ARG2
    jarFileUris:
    - file:///usr/lib/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples.jar
    mainClass: org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount
    properties:
      spark.driver.cores: '2'
      spark.driver.memory: 10g
      spark.driver.userClassPathFirst: 'true'
      spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled: 'false'
      spark.executor.cores: '3'
      spark.executor.memory: 5g
      spark.executor.userClassPathFirst: 'true'
      spark.jars.packages: com.google.cloud:google-cloud-logging:2.2.0
      spark.num.executors: '2'
  stepId: create_try1
name: projects/your-project-id/regions/europe-west3/workflowTemplates/try1
placement:
  managedCluster:
    clusterName: mycluster
updateTime: '2021-08-25T03:30:47.365244Z'
version: 3
```

Copy over the generated yaml config, open a text editor and add `parameters:` field.  It will contain your arguments to accept.

```
parameters:
- name: ARG1
  fields:
  - jobs['create_try1'].sparkJob.args[0] # use the stepId in jobs[], in this example it is 'create_try1'
- name: ARG2
  fields:
  - jobs['create_try1'].sparkJob.args[1]
```

In this example I placed it after `stepId:`.

**Edited yaml config:**

```
id: try1
jobs:
- sparkJob:
    args:
    - ARG1
    - ARG2
    jarFileUris:
    - file:///usr/lib/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples.jar
    mainClass: org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount
    properties:
      spark.driver.cores: '2'
      spark.driver.memory: 10g
      spark.driver.userClassPathFirst: 'true'
      spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled: 'false'
      spark.executor.cores: '3'
      spark.executor.memory: 5g
      spark.executor.userClassPathFirst: 'true'
      spark.jars.packages: com.google.cloud:google-cloud-logging:2.2.0
      spark.num.executors: '2'
  stepId: create_try1
parameters:
- name: ARG1
  fields:
  - jobs['create_try1'].sparkJob.args[0]
- name: ARG2
  fields:
  - jobs['create_try1'].sparkJob.args[1]
name: projects/your-project-id/regions/europe-west3/workflowTemplates/try1
placement:
  managedCluster:
    clusterName: mycluster
updateTime: '2021-08-25T03:13:25.014685Z'
version: 3
```

Use the edited yaml file to overwrite your workflow template:

```
gcloud dataproc workflow-templates import try1 \
    --region=europe-west3 \
    --source=config.yaml
```

Run template using `gcloud dataproc workflow-templates instantiate`:

[image]

For more details you can refer to [Parameterization of Workflow Templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/workflows/workflow-parameters).

Comment: thanks , when I go to load the configuration file I get errors.

`ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.workflow-templates.import) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "parameters" at 'template.jobs[0]': Cannot find field.
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "fields" at 'template.jobs[1]': Cannot find field.
..
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"parameters\" at 'template.jobs[0]':\
      \ Cannot find field."
    field: template.jobs[0]`

Comment: Can you edit your post and include the yaml file?

Comment: @OnofrioCiliberti I tested your yaml and field `parameter:` should not be indented. Try deleting the space prior to `parameter:`.

Comment: I confirm, it is very linked to spaces :(, now I try the launch. You were very kind